# Determine which .net assembly loaded another

Tags: c#, .net

I am subscribing to the AppDomain.AssemblyLoaded event, and wish to know from which assembly the requested (currently being loaded) assembly is loaded from.

If Assembly A contains a call to Assembly.Load(AssemblyB) I want to determine at runtime that Assembly A caused Assembly B to be loaded.

Comment: I don't belive it's possible, when an assembly is loaded it's added to the AppDomain assemblies and no reference to the assembly which loaded it is preserved.

Comment: I don't know how reliable it will be, but maybe use the [`StackTrace`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.stacktrace(v=vs.110).aspx) class and see who was higher up the call stack before the AssemblyLoaded event happened?

Comment: Maybe you are over-complicating this.  If A somehow affects the location of B then surely A was loaded by your event handler as well.  So "last one" or "previous ones" ought to be somewhat relevant.  Don't over-complicate it, DLL Hell is nasty.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will get you the referencing assembly(ies), which is somewhat close.  I'm not sure if it's possible to get more detail.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
  AppDomain.CurrentDomain.AssemblyLoad += new AssemblyLoadEventHandler(MyAssemblyLoadEventHandler);
  System.Data.DataColumn d = new System.Data.DataColumn();
  Console.ReadLine();
}
static void MyAssemblyLoadEventHandler(object sender, AssemblyLoadEventArgs args)
{
  Console.WriteLine("ASSEMBLY LOADED: " + args.LoadedAssembly.FullName);
  string loadedAssemblyFullName = args.LoadedAssembly.FullName;
  foreach (System.Reflection.Assembly parent in AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies())
  {
    System.Reflection.AssemblyName[] referencedAssemblies = parent.GetReferencedAssemblies();
    string[] referencedFullNames = (from r in referencedAssemblies select r.FullName).ToArray();
    if (referencedFullNames.Contains(loadedAssemblyFullName))
    {
      Console.WriteLine(System.IO.Path.GetFileName(args.LoadedAssembly.CodeBase) +
                        " was referenced by " +
                        System.IO.Path.GetFileName(parent.CodeBase));
    }
  }
}
```

Output:

> ASSEMBLY LOADED: System.Numerics, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089
>
> System.Numerics.dll was referenced by System.Core.dll
>
> System.Numerics.dll was referenced by System.Data.dll

Code butchered from: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.assembly.getreferencedassemblies(v=vs.110).aspx

(Edit removed previous unhelpful answer)

Comment: That code will only tell which assembly is calling the actual method, not which assembly loaded an specified assembly.

Comment: Edited in the hopes of actually answering the question, thanks for the input.

Comment: Again the answer is incorrect, this will tell which assembly references which one, so per example you create a DLL and reference mscorlib.dll, that doesn't means your library has loaded mscorlib in memory because it was already loaded... THe same aplies to exteranl libs, supoes A, B, C, A references C and B references C, A loads C, then B is load externally, if you use your code then it will yield that A and B loaded C.

Comment: @Gusman - It's not perfect, but I think it's as good as it gets.